# JSON Parsing with swift 3 to extract data

Tags: json, swift3, extract

The following is the JSON result i am getting by using

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

But i am unable to extract the title, author_data["name"] & summary from data.

I want to store the data in local variables. How do i do it?

**JSON Result:**

```
{
"current_page" = 1;
data =     (
            {
        "author_data" =             (
                            {
                id = "kiyosaki_robert_t";
                name = "Kiyosaki, Robert T.";
            }
        );
        "awards_text" = "";
        "book_id" = "rich_dads_the_business_school_a01";
        "dewey_decimal" = "";
        "dewey_normal" = 0;
        "edition_info" = "Hardcover; 2008-08-30";
        isbn10 = 8186775811;
        isbn13 = 9788186775813;
        language = "";
        "lcc_number" = "";
        "marc_enc_level" = "~";
        notes = "";
        "physical_description_text" = "6.1\"x9.1\"x0.4\"; 0.4 lb";
        "publisher_id" = "manjul_publishing_house_pvt_lt";
        "publisher_name" = "Manjul Publishing House Pvt Ltd";
        "publisher_text" = "Manjul Publishing House Pvt Ltd";
        "subject_ids" =             (
            "business_investing_general"
        );
        summary = "Presents eight hidden values of a network marketing business. This book is suitable for those associated with network marketing.";
        title = "Rich Dad's the Business School";
        "title_latin" = "Rich Dad's the Business School";
        "title_long" = "";
        "urls_text" = "";
    }
);
"index_searched" = isbn;
"page_count" = 1;
"result_count" = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily access data from `Dictionary` if you use Swift native Dictionary instead of `NSDictionary` also with native Dictionary there is no need to specify the `mutableContainers` option. Now your `data` is Array of `Dictionary` and `author_data` is Array within first `Dictionary` of `data` Array you can get its name like this way.

```
if let jsonDic = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
    if let dataArray = jsonDic["data"] as? [[String:Any]], let firstObj = dataArray.first {
        if let summary = firstObj["summary"] as? String, 
           let author_data = firstObj["author_data"] as? [[String:Any]],
           let authorObj = author_data.first, 
           let name = authorObj["name"] {
             print(summary)
             print(name)
        }
    }
}
```